# Roaming Profiles on Ubuntu server using samba with linux mint clients

Tags: networking, server, samba, domain-server

good day to everyone. right now we have a server client set up where our server is ubuntu using samba and our clients are using linux mint. well everything is working well with the log in to local server and such. but I want to ask is there a way that we could set up a roaming profile that everytime we log in on a different pc with a linux mint os too we will have the same profile/setup and we can access our files there then have our own domain in our server? If it is possible I would love to ask for your help on doing so. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

yes roaming profiles are fairly easy within kerboros server realm or using active directory mode of SAMBA (suffer the pangs of Windows ideas and compatibility).

Either way you are setting up an external shared authentication database which can be used in place of local PC credentials to access network services and shares at every network logon. That is the key part which then leads to scripts in SAMBA [netlogon] shares that do common roaming setup tasks and setup automatic logon to [home] whichever way you decide to do it. That is SAMBA can provide individual personal shares or common network shares based on PC or with scripts shared group workspaces etc.

As far I can go except to note that the SAMBA version of Windows Active Domain Controller falls out with very little additional reading and no more servers.  But are you sure SAMBA is the right flavor of *NIX file server for your *NIX network? NFS might be better if Windows clients are not a factor.

A Kerberos realm controller however like most worthwhile *NIX ideas is a bigger commitment to learning, configuration and hardware resources...and probably far more beneficial in the long run if Windows concepts are minimized in what sounds like a strong and pure *NIX environment. Better solution if you go NFS or some other native *NIX file server approach.